# Firebaseでメールアドレスに名前とプロフィール画像を紐付けたい

Tags: swift, ios, swift3, firebase, xcode8

今できてること
・メールアドレスとパスワードによるログイン

Firebaseでログイン機能は出来たのですが、アカウントに名前とできればプロフィール画像を紐付けたいと思ってます。これをやるにはどういったコードを書けば良いのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

Swiftのコードは次の通りです

```
let changeRequest = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.profileChangeRequest()
changeRequest?.photoURL = photoURL
changeRequest?.commitChanges() { (error) in
  // ...
}
```

Firebaseのドキュメントのユーザの管理にコードがあります。
最新の情報はそちらを参照してみてください。

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users?hl=ja#update_a_users_profile

Comment: ありがとうございます！無事紐付けることが出来ました